# web sockets work with local nginx and npm run dev but not docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I have a react front end and nodejs backend, serving and load balancing with nginx. My setup works when I run nginx locally and npm run dev but web sockets fail to connect when I run it through docker containers with docker compose.
In the console:

```
websocket.js:43 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/socket.io/?userId=6500d7f273ec607346da303c&EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:
```

I am at a loss, I've tried everything I can find. Here is my setup.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  ws1:
    image: bark-mate-be
    environment:
      - APPID=1111
      - APPPORT=8081
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
  ws2:
    image: bark-mate-be
    environment:
      - APPID=2222
      - APPPORT=8082
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
  ws3:
    image: bark-mate-be
    environment:
      - APPID=3333
      - APPPORT=8083
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
  barkmatefrontend:
    image: bark-mate-fe
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
      - loadbalancing
    depends_on:
      - db
      - ws1
      - ws2
      - ws3
  db:
    volumes:
      - barkMate_db:/data/db
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  barkMate_db:
networks:
  loadbalancing:
```

***nginx.conf***

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }


upstream loadbalancer {
    # ip_hash;
    hash $remote_addr consistent;
    server ws1:8081;
    server ws2:8082;
}


server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /socket.io/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
            proxy_buffering on;  
        }

         location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;        
        }

}
```

***socketio.js***

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

export let socket = io("http://localhost:80", {
  path: "/socket.io/",
  auth: { token: "token" },
  query: { userId: user ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))._id : "" },
  autoConnect: false,
  transports: ["websocket"],
  withCredentials: true,
});

socket.onAnyOutgoing((e, m) => {
   console.log("any out going", e, m);
});

socket.on("connect", () => {
   console.log("socket has connected");
  socket.emit("message", {
    type: "test",
    content: {
      msg: "test message",
      userId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))._id,
    },
  });
});

socket.on("message", (msg) => {
   console.log("client recieved the message", msg);
});

socket.io.on("reconnect", (attempt) => {
   console.log("socket reconnection success");
});
```

**Dockerfile //client**

```
FROM node:current-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm ci --production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable
COPY --from=build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work by omitting the url in the socket initialization as so:

in ***socketio.js***

```
export let socket = io({
  path: "/socket.io/",
  auth: { token: "token" },
  query: { userId: user ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))._id : "" },
  autoConnect: false,
  transports: ["websocket"],
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

As of right now i'm not sure exactly why I couldn't hit the url the same way as in development ie pointing it at the nginx server. My thoughts are it couldn't hit localhost because it should be referenced by it's service name, so i'd have to hit the nginx image with a different url, i'm just not sure what that would be since it's built as a multi-stage build in the front end Dockerfile and not listed as a service in docker-compose.yml. Would I point the socket url at the front end image service name? doesn't sound right... Or I could build nginx and front end separately and list nginx as a service in docker-compose.yml and reach it at that service name, but I thought the multi-stage build within front end image was best practice. Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

—-edit

Further thinking it I believe requests from my react app are setup to hit nginx during the front end image build and the location blocks in server directives of nginx.conf pick up the path of socket connection so this is why I can leave the url blank and just add the path.